# Cordova File-Transfer download http status 401 - ONLY ANDROID

Tags: android, file-transfer, cordova-plugins

I'm trying to download file from server in my phonegap cordova application. Function looks like this:

```
fileTransfer.download(uri, localPath, success_callback, error_callback, true, { 'headers': {Connection: "close"}, 'chunkedMode': 'false' });
```

In my error_callback function I get:

> ERROR: Download error source: http://xxx.pl/media/images/file_name.png
>   ERROR: Download error target: file:///storage/emulated/0/imgcache//44b337d46e8bdc29d9bccd6499c54860eb348990.png
>   ERROR: Download error code: 3 http_status: 401

The same code works properly on iOS.
Additionally if I try to display image directly from server like this: `<img src="http://xxx.pl/media/images/file_name.png">` it also works properly.

In my config.xml I have: `<access origin="*" />`
Cordova version: 3.4.1-0.1.0
PhoneGap version: 4.2.0-0.24.2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have kind of same 401 problem, i needed to add

```
$ cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-whitelist
```

to my app and then adding these

```
<access origin="*" subdomains="true" />
<allow-navigation href="http://*/*" />
<allow-navigation href="https://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
```

to config.xml. This resolved my problem.

Hope it helps.